# stm32 : How to synchronize DAC, ADC together?

Tags: synchronization, stm32, adc, dac, triangular

I am using stm32L476 discovery board. I am trying to generate triangular wave with DAC. I am using two lookup tables for the DAC(1 for each up slope and down slope). I am giving sine wave at ADC input and I am getting some samples in triangular wave up slope time and down slope time. I start ADC and DAC together for up slope as well as down slope. I am calculating FFT of ADC samples. FOr up slope data, I start calculating FFT at down slope DAC conversion start and for down slope ADC samples FFT, I start calculating FFT after down slope DAC conversion completion. I have put all the necessary to ensure proper start and end timings of the processes of DAC, ADC and FFT. 
The problem is when I am running DAC at high speed(about 500 KSPS), the waveform appears for some seconds and afterwards the output becomes flat. The output waveform becomes flat on the peak side of wave.
When I decrease the DAC speed to around 400 KSPS, the problem does not occur. 
Also, when I use HAL delay after the down slope FFT completion, the issue is resolved and the wave appears properly for all the DAC speeds. But I don't want to waste any time there. 
Below is the code. Anyone knows what the issue is here?

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"
#include "arm_math.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "arm_const_structs.h"

#define buf_size 128

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc2;

DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dac_ch2;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim7;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim15;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart3_rx;

void calculate_myfft(int32_t* buf);

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM7_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM15_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);

int buf_size1 = buf_size;
const uint16_t val1[]={8,16,25,33,41,49,57,66,
        74,82,90,98,106,115,123,131,
        139,147,156,164,172,180,188,197,
        205,213,221,229,238,246,254,262,
        270,278,287,295,303,311,319,328,
        336,344,352,360,369,377,385,393,
        401,410,418,426,434,442,450,459,
        467,475,483,491,500,508,516,524,
        532,541,549,557,565,573,581,590,
        598,606,614,622,631,639,647,655,
        663,672,680,688,696,704,713,721,
        729,737,745,753,762,770,778,786,
        794,803,811,819,827,835,844,852,
        860,868,876,885,893,901,909,917,
        925,934,942,950,958,966,975,983,
        991,999,1007,1016,1024,1032,1040,1048,
        1057,1065,1073,1081,1089,1097,1106,1114,
        1122,1130,1138,1147,1155,1163,1171,1179,
        1188,1196,1204,1212,1220,1229,1237,1245,
        1253,1261,1269,1278,1286,1294,1302,1310,
        1319,1327,1335,1343,1351,1360,1368,1376,
        1384,1392,1400,1409,1417,1425,1433,1441,
        1450,1458,1466,1474,1482,1491,1499,1507,
        1515,1523,1532,1540,1548,1556,1564,1572,
        1581,1589,1597,1605,1613,1622,1630,1638,
        1646,1654,1663,1671,1679,1687,1695,1704,
        1712,1720,1728,1736,1744,1753,1761,1769,
        1777,1785,1794,1802,1810,1818,1826,1835,
        1843,1851,1859,1867,1876,1884,1892,1900,
        1908,1916,1925,1933,1941,1949,1957,1966,
        1974,1982,1990,1998,2007,2015,2023,2031,
        2039,2048,2056,2064,2072,2080,2088,2097,
        2105,2113,2121,2129,2138,2146,2154,2162,
        2170,2179,2187,2195,2203,2211,2219,2228,
        2236,2244,2252,2260,2269,2277,2285,2293,
        2301,2310,2318,2326,2334,2342,2351,2359,
        2367,2375,2383,2391,2400,2408,2416,2424,
        2432,2441,2449,2457,2465,2473,2482,2490,
        2498,2506,2514,2523,2531,2539,2547,2555,
        2563,2572,2580,2588,2596,2604,2613,2621,
        2629,2637,2645,2654,2662,2670,2678,2686,
        2695,2703,2711,2719,2727,2735,2744,2752,
        2760,2768,2776,2785,2793,2801,2809,2817,
        2826,2834,2842,2850,2858,2867,2875,2883,
        2891,2899,2907,2916,2924,2932,2940,2948,
        2957,2965,2973,2981,2989,2998,3006,3014,
        3022,3030,3038,3047,3055,3063,3071,3079,
        3088,3096,3104,3112,3120,3129,3137,3145,
        3153,3161,3170,3178,3186,3194,3202,3210,
        3219,3227,3235,3243,3251,3260,3268,3276,
        3284,3292,3301,3309,3317,3325,3333,3342,
        3350,3358,3366,3374,3382,3391,3399,3407,
        3415,3423,3432,3440,3448,3456,3464,3473,
        3481,3489,3497,3505,3514,3522,3530,3538,
        3546,3554,3563,3571,3579,3587,3595,3604,
        3612,3620,3628,3636,3645,3653,3661,3669,
        3677,3686,3694,3702,3710,3718,3726,3735,
        3743,3751,3759,3767,3776,3784,3792,3800,
        3808,3817,3825,3833,3841,3849,3857,3866,
        3874,3882,3890,3898,3907,3915,3923,3931,
        3939,3948,3956,3964,3972,3980,3989,3997,
        4005,4013,4021,4029,4038,4046,4054,4062,
        4070,4079,4087,4095};

const uint16_t val2[] = {
        4087,4079,4070,4062,
                4054,4046,4038,4029,4021,4013,4005,3997,
                3989,3980,3972,3964,3956,3948,3939,3931,
                3923,3915,3907,3898,3890,3882,3874,3866,
                3857,3849,3841,3833,3825,3817,3808,3800,
                3792,3784,3776,3767,3759,3751,3743,3735,
                3726,3718,3710,3702,3694,3686,3677,3669,
                3661,3653,3645,3636,3628,3620,3612,3604,
                3595,3587,3579,3571,3563,3554,3546,3538,
                3530,3522,3514,3505,3497,3489,3481,3473,
                3464,3456,3448,3440,3432,3423,3415,3407,
                3399,3391,3382,3374,3366,3358,3350,3342,
                3333,3325,3317,3309,3301,3292,3284,3276,
                3268,3260,3251,3243,3235,3227,3219,3210,
                3202,3194,3186,3178,3170,3161,3153,3145,
                3137,3129,3120,3112,3104,3096,3088,3079,
                3071,3063,3055,3047,3038,3030,3022,3014,
                3006,2998,2989,2981,2973,2965,2957,2948,
                2940,2932,2924,2916,2907,2899,2891,2883,
                2875,2867,2858,2850,2842,2834,2826,2817,
                2809,2801,2793,2785,2776,2768,2760,2752,
                2744,2735,2727,2719,2711,2703,2695,2686,
                2678,2670,2662,2654,2645,2637,2629,2621,
                2613,2604,2596,2588,2580,2572,2563,2555,
                2547,2539,2531,2523,2514,2506,2498,2490,
                2482,2473,2465,2457,2449,2441,2432,2424,
                2416,2408,2400,2391,2383,2375,2367,2359,
                2351,2342,2334,2326,2318,2310,2301,2293,
                2285,2277,2269,2260,2252,2244,2236,2228,
                2219,2211,2203,2195,2187,2179,2170,2162,
                2154,2146,2138,2129,2121,2113,2105,2097,
                2088,2080,2072,2064,2056,2048,2039,2031,
                2023,2015,2007,1998,1990,1982,1974,1966,
                1957,1949,1941,1933,1925,1916,1908,1900,
                1892,1884,1876,1867,1859,1851,1843,1835,
                1826,1818,1810,1802,1794,1785,1777,1769,
                1761,1753,1744,1736,1728,1720,1712,1704,
                1695,1687,1679,1671,1663,1654,1646,1638,
                1630,1622,1613,1605,1597,1589,1581,1572,
                1564,1556,1548,1540,1532,1523,1515,1507,
                1499,1491,1482,1474,1466,1458,1450,1441,
                1433,1425,1417,1409,1400,1392,1384,1376,
                1368,1360,1351,1343,1335,1327,1319,1310,
                1302,1294,1286,1278,1269,1261,1253,1245,
                1237,1229,1220,1212,1204,1196,1188,1179,
                1171,1163,1155,1147,1138,1130,1122,1114,
                1106,1097,1089,1081,1073,1065,1057,1048,
                1040,1032,1024,1016,1007,999,991,983,
                975,966,958,950,942,934,925,917,
                909,901,893,885,876,868,860,852,
                844,835,827,819,811,803,794,786,
                778,770,762,753,745,737,729,721,
                713,704,696,688,680,672,663,655,
                647,639,631,622,614,606,598,590,
                581,573,565,557,549,541,532,524,
                516,508,500,491,483,475,467,459,
                450,442,434,426,418,410,401,393,
                385,377,369,360,352,344,336,328,
                319,311,303,295,287,278,270,262,
                254,246,238,229,221,213,205,197,
                188,180,172,164,156,147,139,131,
                123,115,106,98,90,82,74,66,
                57,49,41,33,25,16,8,0};

int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int count3 = 0;
int count4 = 0;
int count5 = 0;
int count6 = 0;
int count7 = 0;
int run_buf = 0;

uint16_t ADC1ConvertedValues[buf_size];
uint16_t ADC1ConvertedValues2[buf_size];
const int lengthofa = sizeof( ADC1ConvertedValues ) / sizeof( ADC1ConvertedValues[0] );
int32_t ADC1ConvertedValues91[buf_size];
int32_t ADC1ConvertedValues92[buf_size];
int32_t data_output1_temp1[buf_size];
int32_t data_output1_temp2[buf_size];
int16_t data_arrayh1[buf_size];
int16_t data_output[2*buf_size];
float hann[buf_size];

int run_adc = 0;
int dac_half_conv_cmpt = 0;
int adc_conv_cmpt = 0; 
int fft_flag = 0;;

int slope = 1;
int restart_dac = 0;
int fft_2_goingon = 0;
int timer15_start = 0;
int l1 = 0;
int l2 = 0;
int some_delay = 0;
int start_next_chirp = 0;
int start_fft = 0;
int dac_conv_cmpt = 0;
int timer15_started = 0;
int run_buf_was_6 = 0;

uint8_t data[2];
uint8_t var1;
uint8_t var3;
uint8_t var2;
uint8_t var4;
uint8_t var5;
uint8_t var6;

int i = 0;
int16_t i_buf[buf_size];
int send_to_usart = 0;

int fft1 = 0;
int fft2 = 0;

uint8_t *g;
int fft1_count = 0;
int fft2_count = 0;
int ready_for_next_chirp = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int p = 0;
    int n1=sizeof(val1);
    l1=n1/sizeof(val1[0]);
    int n2=sizeof(val2);
    l2=n2/sizeof(val2[0]);
  HAL_Init();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC2_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  MX_TIM7_Init();
  MX_TIM15_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();

    g = &data[0];
    HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart3, (uint8_t*)g, 1);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim7);
    HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2);
    HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2, (uint32_t*)val1, l1, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc2, (uint32_t*)&ADC1ConvertedValues, buf_size);
    for (p = 0; p < buf_size; p++)
          {
              hann[p] = 0.54 - 0.46 * cosf((2*PI*p)/(buf_size-1));
          }

    while (1)
    {
      if((run_buf == 1) && (ready_for_next_chirp == 1))
          {
              //HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(&htim15);
              send_to_usart = 0;
              //HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim15);
              MX_TIM15_Init();
              ready_for_next_chirp = 0;
              //HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15);
              count2 += 1;
              run_buf_was_6 = 0;
              run_buf = 3;
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim7);
              HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim7);
              HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2);
              HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2, (uint32_t*)val1, l1, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
              HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc2, (uint32_t*)&ADC1ConvertedValues, buf_size);
              //slope = 1;
              //start_fft = 1;
          }

          else if(run_buf == 2)
          {
              run_buf = 4;
              count3 += 1;
              //dac_conv_cmpt = 0;
              HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2);
              HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim7);
              HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim7);
              HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2, (uint32_t*)val2, l2, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
              fft_flag = 0;
              slope = 1;
              start_fft = 1;
          }

          if(some_delay == 1)
          {
              some_delay = 0;
              count7 += 1;
              //HAL_DAC_Stop_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_2);
              HAL_Delay(1);
              timer15_started = 1;
              fft_flag = 0;
              run_buf = 1;
              //HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim15);
          }

          if((start_fft == 1) && (slope == 1))
                {
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, SET);
              start_fft = 0;
              fft1 = 1;
              count5 += 1;
                      //count += 1;
                      //adc_conv_cmpt = 0;
                      //fft_flag = 0;
                      for(int j=0; j<buf_size; j++)
                          {
                                ADC1ConvertedValues91[j] = (int32_t)((int32_t)(ADC1ConvertedValues[j]) - 2048);
                          }
                      calculate_myfft(ADC1ConvertedValues91);
                      fft_flag = 1;
                      fft1 = 0;
                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_6, RESET);
                  }
            else if((start_fft == 1) && (slope == 2))
                  {
                      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, SET);
                      start_fft = 0;
                      count6 += 1;
                      fft2 = 1;
                      timer15_started = 0;
                      //count1 += 1;
                      //adc_conv_cmpt = 0;
                      //fft_flag = 3;
                      for(int j=0; j<buf_size; j++)
                          {
                                ADC1ConvertedValues92[j] = (int32_t)((int32_t)(ADC1ConvertedValues2[j]) - 2048);
                          }
                      fft_2_goingon = 1;
                      //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, SET);
                      calculate_myfft(ADC1ConvertedValues92);
                      fft_2_goingon =0;
                      fft_flag = 2;
                      fft2 = 0;
                      send_to_usart = 1;
                      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, RESET);
                      some_delay = 1;
                      ready_for_next_chirp = 1;
                  }

        if((data[0] == 0x43) && (send_to_usart == 1))
                  {
                      send_to_usart = 0;
                      data[0] = 0x00;
                      data_output1_temp1[0] = 0;
                      data_output1_temp1[1] = 0;
                      for(i=0; i<buf_size; i++)
                                                 {
                                                     var3 = (data_output1_temp1[i] & 0x000000FF);
                                                     //while(adc_go != 0);
                                                     HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var3, 1, 5);


                                                     var1 = ((data_output1_temp1[i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);                                                 
                                             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var1, 1, 5);                                           
                                                     var2 = ((data_output1_temp1[i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                                                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var2, 1, 5);

                                                    var4 = ((data_output1_temp1[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
                                                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var4, 1, 5);

                                                 }

                  }

        if((data[0] == 0x41) && (send_to_usart == 1))
                  {
                      send_to_usart = 0;
                      data[0] = 0x00;
                      for(i=0; i<buf_size; i++)
                                                 {

                                                     var5 = (ADC1ConvertedValues91[i] & 0x00FF);

                                                     HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var5, 1, 5);                                                        
                                                     var6 = ((ADC1ConvertedValues91[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8);                                                          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var6, 1, 5);                                                       
                                                 }  
                  }

        if((data[0] == 0x44) && (send_to_usart == 1))
                          {
                              send_to_usart = 0;
                              data[0] = 0x00;
                              data_output1_temp2[0] = 0;
                              data_output1_temp2[1] = 0;
                              for(i=0; i<buf_size; i++)
                                                         {

                                                             var3 = (data_output1_temp2[i] & 0x000000FF);

                                                             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var3, 1, 5);


                                                             var1 = ((data_output1_temp2[i] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);

                                                             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var1, 1, 5);


                                                             var2 = ((data_output1_temp2[i] & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                                                            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var2, 1, 5);

                                                            var4 = ((data_output1_temp2[i] & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var4, 1, 5);

                                                         }
                              //data[0] = 0x00;
                          }

                if((data[0] == 0x42) && (send_to_usart == 1))
                          {
                              send_to_usart = 0;
                              data[0] = 0x00;
                              for(i=0; i<buf_size; i++)
                                                         {

                                                             var5 = (ADC1ConvertedValues92[i] & 0x00FF);
                                                             //while(adc_go != 0);
                                                             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var5, 1, 5);


                                                             var6 = ((ADC1ConvertedValues92[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
                                                             //while(adc_go != 1);
                                                             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &var6, 1, 5);
                                                             //HAL_Delay(5);

                                                         }
                              //data[0] = 0x00;
                          }

    }

}

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    adc_conv_cmpt = 1;
    count += 1;
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}

void calculate_myfft(int32_t* buf)
{
    //fft_flag = 2;
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //int SAMPLE_LENGTH = 32;

    uint32_t fftSize = buf_size;


    /*for (n = 0; n < buf_size; n++)
        {
            hann[n] = 0.54 - 0.46 * cosf((2*PI*n)/(buf_size-1));
        }*/

    for(n = 0; n < buf_size; n++)
    {
        data_arrayh1[n] = (int16_t)(hann[n]*buf[n]);
    }

    uint32_t ifftFlag = 0;  //to be set when inverse FFT is to be performed
    uint32_t doBitReverse = 1; // Set bit reversal for DIF and DIT selection
    volatile arm_status status;
    arm_rfft_instance_q15 instance;
    arm_rfft_init_q15(&instance, fftSize, ifftFlag, doBitReverse);
    arm_rfft_q15(&instance, data_arrayh1, data_output);

    if(fft1 == 1)
    {
        fft1_count += 1;
        for(i=0; i<(2*buf_size); i=i+2)
        {
            data_output1_temp1[i/2] = (int32_t)((data_output[i] * data_output[i]) + (data_output[i+1] * data_output[i+1]));
            //data_output1_plot[i/2] = data_output1_temp[i/2];
            //fft_flag = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(fft2 == 1)
    {
        fft2_count += 1;
        for(i=0; i<(2*buf_size); i=i+2)
            {
                data_output1_temp2[i/2] = (int32_t)((data_output[i] * data_output[i]) + (data_output[i+1] * data_output[i+1]));
            }
    }
}

void HAL_DACEx_ConvCpltCallbackCh2(DAC_HandleTypeDef* hdac)
{
    count1 += 1;
    //dac_conv_cmpt = 1;
    HAL_TIM_Base_Stop(&htim7);
    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim7);

    if(run_buf == 3)
    {
        run_buf = 2;
        //run_buf = 4;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc2, (uint32_t*)&ADC1ConvertedValues2, buf_size);
        //HAL_Delay(3);
        //some_delay = 1;
    }
    else if(run_buf == 4)
    {
        run_buf = 6;
        //HAL_Delay(3);
        run_buf_was_6 = 1;
        slope = 2;
        start_fft = 1;
        //some_delay = 1;
    }
    else if(run_buf == 0)
    {
        run_buf = 2;
        //run_buf = 4;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc2, (uint32_t*)&ADC1ConvertedValues2, buf_size);
    }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;


  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART3|RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart3ClockSelection = RCC_USART3CLKSOURCE_SYSCLK;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLLSAI1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Source = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1M = 1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1N = 34;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1P = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Q = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1R = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1ClockOut = RCC_PLLSAI1_ADC1CLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);


  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);


  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}


static void MX_ADC2_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

  hadc2.Instance = ADC2;
  hadc2.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV1;
  hadc2.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc2.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc2.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc2.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc2.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.NbrOfDiscConversion = 1;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc2.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc2.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc2.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc2.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_47CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc2, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

static void MX_DAC1_Init(void)
{

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }


  sConfig.DAC_SampleAndHold = DAC_SAMPLEANDHOLD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_T7_TRGO;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_ConnectOnChipPeripheral = DAC_CHIPCONNECT_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_UserTrimming = DAC_TRIMMING_FACTORY;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

static void MX_TIM7_Init(void)
{

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim7.Instance = TIM7;
  htim7.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim7.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim7.Init.Period = 79;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim7) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim7, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

static void MX_TIM15_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim15.Instance = TIM15;
  htim15.Init.Prescaler = 39;
  htim15.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim15.Init.Period = 2000;
  htim15.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim15.Init.RepetitionCounter = 1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim15) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim15, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim15, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart3.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart3.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}


static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{

  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn);

}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;


  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA4 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  HAL_I2CEx_EnableFastModePlus(I2C_FASTMODEPLUS_PB6);
  HAL_I2CEx_EnableFastModePlus(I2C_FASTMODEPLUS_PB7);

}
void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
  while(1) 
  {
  }

}
#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{

}

#endif
```

Comment: Are you joking. Strip the code and the question to the absolute minimum. 500ksps is very slow. Stm32 dacs can do much better - my personal record is 6.5MSPS.

Comment: PS. HAL adds such a ridiculous overhead and you should program this kind of programme bare register

Comment: Sorry for the long post. I don't need dac running at high speeds for this application. For my application, 500KSPS is enough. Although I was not able to increase dac speed beyond 500KSPS when tried. I would try using bare registers but I would really like to know the problem in this code.